# Unable to upload app even when admin

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having trouble uploading a new build to an existing app in app store. The error I am getting is

> permissions failure, your account does not have permission to create
>   iOS Distribution certificates

I know what the error means but it doesn't make any sense as my developer account is an admin user.

My account was added to a previous companies developer account that required me to modify the code and resubmit. I have checked the permissions in iTunes Connect and I can see I am an admin. I have checked the bundle ID and they match to the previous app.

In xCode, I can select the correct team. In the Accounts section it says that I am a member of the team. I have tries removing the profile, quiting xcode and re-adding but nothing seems to fix the issue. I can build and install through xCode.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: It's Xcode, not xCode

Answer (score 0):

Please add run certificate which is responsible for current team and current provisioning profiles. As I understand, at this moment you have all provisioning profiles and permissions but Keychain does't know current permissions so run certificates again if you have done it already and delete expired ones. Please give a follow up.

Comment: Didn't help. I removed all certs and re-added them. xCode added them automatically.

Comment: Can u access itunesConnect of the current team?